# Does the pre-merge commit hook get executed when I click merge request button in github?

Tags: node.js, git, githooks

I want to update the package version automatically when I create a pull request from release branch to master and after that I want whenever I merge it, the pre-merge git hook will be executed to launch another script.

pre-merge-commit:

```
cd my_app
    node ./hooks/post-commit-version
    RETVAL=$?

    if [ $RETVAL -ne 0 ]
    then
       exit 1
    fi
```

hooks/post-commit-version:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
const path = require('path');
const moment = require('moment');
const fs = require('fs');

function getBranch(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
        exec(
            "git branch | grep '*'",
            function (err, stdout, stderr) {
                if(err)reject(err)
                const name = stdout.replace('* ','').replace('\n','');
                resolve(name)
            }
        )
    });
}

getBranch()
    .then((branch) => {
        if(branch === 'release') {
          const currentDate = moment().format('YY.MM.DD')
        var pathToFile = path.join(__dirname, "../package.json");

        if (fs.existsSync(pathToFile)) {
          const data = fs.readFileSync(pathToFile, 'utf-8')
          const content = JSON.parse(data);
          content.version = currentDate;
          fs.writeFileSync(pathToFile, JSON.stringify(content, null, 2), 'utf8');
          exec(`git add ${pathToFile}`, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
            if(err) console.log(err)
           console.log(stdout)
          })
      } else {
          console.log("Cannot find file : " + pathToFile);
          return;
        }
      }
        return;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
    })
```

When I try this locally, with `pre-commit` hook and execute the git commands manually, it works successfully and update the repository in github as the one I want it to be. But I'm not sure that git hooks are executed in Github server when I click the merge request button.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is no.

Hooks are tied to *one specific repository* and are not transferred by Git operations.<sup>1</sup>  Any hooks you set up in *your* repository are not set up in some other repository.  So the hook you have in your repository acts in and on your repository, but if you have a second clone elsewhere, it does not act in and on that second clone.

Besides this, GitHub use a different mechanism ("GitHub Actions") and just don't let you put any hooks into their repositories in the first place.

---

<sup>1</sup>If your OS provides symbolic links, you can (manually, once per clone) install a symlink as a Git hook, with the symlink pointing to a file in the work-tree for your repository.  In this way, you can get a hook that *is* affected by various operations: since the hook's actual executable code lives in your work-tree, things that affect that file in your work-tree affect the hook.

Similarly, on OSes that don't provide symbolic links, you can (manually, once per clone) install a hook script-or-binary that works by running a script-or-binary out of your work-tree.  That is, rather than relying on the OS's symbolic link mechanism to run the file directly from your work-tree, you write a hook whose "run" operation consists of "run file from work-tree and use its exit status as the hook's exit status".